# rollback parent record if child record is not found

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i have a master detail page in my apex application.
i want to rollback the master table if user not entering data in child table.

Can anyone help me in this scenario ?

Comment: ca you provide your data model ? that is clearly a PK-FK relationship that you can control in APEX , easily.

Comment: Case is that i have written two process , one to insert master record and other to insert child record.
After inserting master record i am returning pk to a variable and using that in child record as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a validation process that runs after both the master and child processes have run; if it raises an exception (e.g. using `raise_application_error`) the entire transaction (all records inserted, updated and deleted) will be rolled back.

You could add a process that checks if a new master record has at least one child, and if a master record is childless, raise the exception.